# Get Host and Login information inside a native-compiled stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, native

SQL Server 2017

I am working on a stored procedure with NATIVE_COMPILATION.
I really need to be able to get various information that you can normally find in master.dbo.sysprocesses  (hostname, program_name, net_address, ...)

So far though, the limitation of the native compiling has blocked me.
It does not allow usage of non memory-optimized tables (such as sysprocesses) and functions like HOST_NAME, ConnectionProperty and SESSION_CONTEXT are not allowed.

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with an `Init` | `Deinit` type of function.

The client (or wrapper normal SP) can get the info needed, pass to Init which stores that off to a table, indexed on the session id.

This also helps to solve for a dead-session.

The client calls `Init` before it does anything else.  If there are resources associated with this session, it is assumed the first user has died and the previous resources are released.

Extremely simplified Pseudo code:

```
function Init(hostname, program_name, net_address, ...)
begin
     if ( isSessionActive(@@spid) )
          releaseSession(@@spid)
     insert into sessionTable values( @@spid, hostname, program_name, net_address )
end
```

```
function Deinit()
begin
     delete from sessionTable where sessid = @@spid
end
```

```
native-compiled procedure doSomething()
begin
     select from sessionTable (...) where sessId = @@spid
     do something with that info . . . . 
end
```